# Which version to use

Tags: server, docker, .desktop

I was thinking of running docker on Ubuntu is there any way to strip down Ubuntu desktop to bare minimum or does Ubuntu server have terminal when you connect it to a display after install thanks

Comment: Install the server version.

Comment: If you do not need a GUI, Ubuntu Server is what you’re looking for.

Comment: But does the server have a terminal gui so if I mess up something with the install I can add something that I need without sshing to the pc

Comment: Yes, you can install the server and you will get a terminal when you connect with the display. You can also change GUI or CLI view if you chose minimal configuration it will give you the default CLI terminal directly. And if you wish to install some additional software and get GUI view then install the full, cause after connecting the Display or not or ssh the server it will be able to give you terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution here would normally be to use Ubuntu Server, since SSH server with access to the command line is included by default.

Some server admins might prefer to install a GUI (to allow for remote desktop) but this can be added afterwards.